# POST method of twitter API is not working

Tags: php, twitter

```
<?php
require 'app_tokens2.php';
require 'tmhOAuth-master/tmhOAuth.php';

$query = htmlspecialchars($_GET['query']);
if (empty($query))
{
    $query = "pitbull";
}
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
    'user_token' => $user_token,
    'user_secret' => $user_secret
));

// Get the timeline with the Twitter API
$http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'),
    array('q' => $query,'count' => 4, 'lang' => 'en'));

// Request was successful
if ($http_code == 200)
{
    // Extract the tweets from the API response
    $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
    $tweet_data = $response['statuses'];
    // Accumulate tweets from results
    $tweet_stream = '[';

    foreach ($tweet_data as $tweet)
    {
        // Add this tweet's text to the results
        $tweet_stream .= '{ "tweet":' . json_encode($tweet['text']) . ' },';
    }

    $tweet_stream = substr($tweet_stream, 0, -1);
    $tweet_stream .= ']';

    // Send the tweets back to the Ajax request
    print $tweet_stream;

    // Connect to Mongo and set DB and Collection
    $mongo = new Mongo();
    $db = $mongo->sample1;
    $collection = $db->trial3;

    // Convert JSON to a PHP array
    $tweet_stream = json_decode($tweet_stream,true);

    // Loop array and create seperate documents for each tweet
    foreach ($tweet_stream as $item)
    {
        $collection->insert($item);
    }

    // fetch all tweets from the collection
    $posts = $collection->find();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        // display the posts
        //print $post;
         print_r($post);     //print_r prints a variable in a more human-readable form: 
    }
    var_dump($collection->count());     //counts number of documents in a collection
}
// Handle errors from API request
else
{
    if ($http_code == 429) 
    {
        print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
    }
    else 
    {
        print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that request';
    }
}
```

The above code is working properly. But the problem is if I use the `post` method it is not working.Gives error message

> 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that request'

I want to use post method to get the geotagged tweets.But when I'm trying the          replacement with post method the error is given.

Comment: _“But when I'm trying the replacement with post”_ – show us _how_ you tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Where would you like to use `POST` method?
If you are going to use it on Search Query, then you can't.

Look at the Twitter [Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) for Search Tweets. You can't use `POST` method. For Search Tweet, you can use only `GET` HTTP method.

Comment: For extracting tweets with its latitude and longitude I need to use post method